# Pi Zero W - SD Corrupt?

Tags: raspberry-pi

I have a super basic python script sending strings from a .txt file to an LCD. It works great, but after it runs for a while I get random characters on the LCD that are not present in the .txt file. Is my SD card semi-corrupted?

Comment: Hmm could you post your python code? It might be the code starts reading from outside of your text file after it reaches the end of the text

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like your script is reading data outside of your 'string' source. It is kind of buffer overflow issue.